# How do I scan my folders for a website? Like a crawler?

Tags: web-crawler

I'd like to scan all the url's on my website as well as get the files in them, but the thing is, there are too many for me to do this manually so how would I do this?

I'd like it formatted anyway as long as there is some type of order to it.

Eg: 
URL/FOLDER
URL/FOLDER/FILE
URL/FOLDER/FILE2
URL/FOLDER2/FILE

All in a file like a .txt

How would I do that?

Comment: What about `wget`, `find`, `ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ls` passing the `-R` switch. It lists subdirectories.
Here is an example:

```
ls -R /path/to/whatever > folders.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, its kinda late. But that was perfect. I was busy fixing everything.